# Many-many relation with specific type

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relations

Sorry if this question has already been asked, but I didn't find it performing a search.

I have 2 tables (`table_a` and `table_b`), linked by a many/many relation.
The relation can be of two types, `type_a` and `type_b`.

I was wondering what was better between:

- Setting a `type` column in the relation table and during queries filter on this field
- Creating 2 relations table, one for each type and apply no filter during queries

I can see advantage in both solutions, but I can't tell which one is generally used to solve this kind of problem

Comment: Can an item from table a and an item from table b be related via both types? Or always via just one type?

Comment: Not it shouldn't be possible

Comment: Then you need one table, to enforce this constraint.

Comment: And performance wise, it won't be a lot worse ?

Comment: Indexing will be a little more complicated but not much of a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks ! May be you could create an answer so I can validate it.

Comment: Sample data (a few records) would help to answer this definitively. Is there a large difference between type_a and type_b - if it's a question of 1 or 2 fields, then I would go with @ypercubeᵀᴹ - but if there's a large difference, I would consider separate tables - with some benchmarking prior to implementation! And if you haven't started yet, I would **definitely** go with PostgreSQL for any database project.

Comment: This is just one field specifying the kind of relations they have

Comment: Fair enough, go with 1 table. Check out what I said about PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm planning to use PostgreSQL ! But I'm interested on why you are recommending it instead of MySQL !

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table); see that for rationale.

For separated tables, each should look similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

For the single table:

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    type ENUM('foo', 'bar') NOT NULL,  -- or TINYINT UNSIGNED  ***
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X  ***
    INDEX      (y_id, type, x_id)       -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

A third option is to put both types in a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    type ENUM('foo', 'bar') NOT NULL,  -- or TINYINT UNSIGNED
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, type, y_id),      -- When starting with X  ***
    INDEX      (y_id, type, x_id)       -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(`***` indicates the only deviation(s) from previous version.)

Which is "best"?  I don't know.  And if you add `FOREIGN KEYs`, things get messier.